# how to create annotation in spring

Tags: spring-boot

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import({
        testMethod.class
})
public @interface test{
    public String value() default "";
}

@Component
public class testMethod{
...
}
```

in my controller, I want to use the annotation I created

```
@test
@RequestMapping(...)
public response getAll(){
...}
```

I put break point in the testMethod, and it could not hit the break point. It seems like it could not find the testMethod component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import a Configuration class. As documented @Import annotation used to import a configuration as follows.

> Indicates one or more {@link Configuration @Configuration} classes to import.

```
public class TestBean {
    public TestBean() {
    }
}

@Configuration
public class TestMethod {
    @Bean
    public TestBean testBean() {
        return new TestBean(); //put break-point here
    }
}
```

Comment: I add @Configuration on the TestMethod, but it still could not find TestMethod

Comment: You need to define some configurations and put a breakpoint there. Edited my  answer by injecting a test bean in configuration.